# problems with multiple files in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html, file-upload

First, I am sorry for my bad English.

I want to upload multiple files to a server using the HTML5 + JavaScript + PHP

With HTML and JS to do as if to simulate do. Operate properly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="lanzar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  >
<input type="file" id="files"  name="files[]" multiple />
<input type="submit" />
<input type="reset"/>
<output id="list"></output>
</form>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have a simple PHP code that goes up the images. My problem is that only up to the last file that has been selected. The case does not rest. It's as if the array is not the correct way of making the data.

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){
    echo $num_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key =>$value){

        is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]);

        $origen = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $destino = "img/".$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing bad?
Thanks

Comment: can you `var_dump($_FILES)` and post the result?

Comment: I try to upload two images test_01.jpg and test_02.jpg and the result is this:

array(1) { ["files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "test_02.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "D:\xampp\tmp\phpB97E.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(66187) } } } 1

Comment: As is evident from the var_dump, you are only receiving the last file on the list- i.e `multiple` doesn't work. Which browser are you using and what version?

Comment: Chrome 23.0.1271.97m and Firefox 17.0.1. Not work in any :(
I do not understand.

But if I do it as follows and it works.
<input type="file" id="files"  name="files[]"/>
<input type="file" id="files"  name="files[]"/>

But I do not like that and do not understand why one way works and the other does not.

Comment: As far as I was working in Chrome and Firefox since version 3.6. The other browsers do not care.

Comment: I have a step ... If an image by first and then another in the array I get that there is only one ... but if I select the two files at once then the array receives two and up the two images or three .... Why then if I do it one at a time does not work?

Comment: If you are keep reopening the select file window and choosing a different file you are simply overriding the last chosen file. Multiple choice means selecting a few files at once

Comment: That just discovered. It was me who did not understand their logic ... anyway Do you know if there is any way to select files from the way I was doing it before?. Now it is simple curiosity :)

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is working fine as i tested it at my local server, all images are being uploaded. please check again.

Comment: You mean it shows you thumbnails or to put in the folder img/ ??